# Is iphone simulator's brightness adjustable?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, brightness, screen-brightness

i tried to use the most of the correct answers suggested by the users to adjust the brightness of the iphone (ie `[[UIScreen mainScreen]setBrightness:0.0];`)  but the simulator didn't change its brightness. Is iphone simulator's brightness adjustable?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The iPhone simulator brightness is not adjustable, you have to try in a real device!

Answer (score 8):

The iPhone simulator is not a hardware simulator. It simulates some of the hardware functions but mostly it is a simulator for iOS. You will need to register a device and test to be able to confirm if your code works properly.

Comment: Put differently, simulator != emulator.